# matplotlib plot does not show up in jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, reinforcement-learning

I'd like to reproduce the learning curve below (in jupyter notebook) which corresponds to the example of the page 637 of the Geron book.

[image]

In particular, here is the code I use:

```
%pylab inline
%matplotlib inline

import tensorflow as tf
from tf import keras
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import deque
import gym

env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")
input_shape = [4]
n_outputs = 2
replay_buffer = deque(maxlen = 1000)
batch_size = 32
discount_factor = 0.95

model = keras.models.sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="elu", input_shape = input_shape),
    keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="elu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(n_outputs)
])

def epsilon_greedy_policy(state, epsilon=0):
    if np.random.rand() < epsilon:
        return np.random.randint(2)
    else:
        Q_values = model.predict(state[np.newaxis])
        return np.argmax(Q_values[0])

def sample_experiences(batch_size):
    indices = np.random.randint(len(replay_buffer), size = batch_size)
    batch = [replay_buffer[index] for index in indices]
    states, actions, rewards, next_states, dones = [
        np.array([experience[field_index] for experience in batch])
        for field_index in range(5)]
    return states, actions, rewards, next_states, dones

def play_one_step(env, state, epsilon):
    action = epsilon_greedy_policy(state, epsilon)
    next_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    replay_buffer.append((state, actions, reward, next_state, done))
    return next_state, reward, done, info

optimizer = keras.optimizer.Adam(lr=1e-3)
loss_fn = keras.losses.mean_squared_error

def training_step(batch_size):
    experiences = sample_experiences(batch_size)
    states, actions, rewards, next_states, dones = experiences
    next_Q_values = model.predict(next_states)
    max_next_Q_values = np.max(next_Q_values, axis=1)
    target_Q_values = (rewards + (1-dones) * discount_factor 8 max_next_Q_values)
    mask = tf.one_hot(actions, n_outputs)
    with tf.GradientTape as tape:
        all_Q_values = model(states)
        Q_values = tf.reduce_mean(all_Q_values * mask, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss_fn(target_Q_values, Q_values))
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.appy_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

ep = []
rew = []
    
for episode in range(600):
    obs = env.reset()
    for step in range(200):
        epsilon = max(1 - episode / 500, 0.01)
        obs, reward, done, info = play_one_step(env, obs, epsilon)
        ep.append(epsilon)
        rew.append(reward)
        if done:
            break
    if episode > 50:
        training_step(batch_size)

plt.plot(ep, rew)
plt.show()
```

The code is exactly as represented in the book except the following points.

1- I added

```
%pylab inline
%matplotlib inline
```

2- I added `ep` and `rew` lists in the training loop to later plot their content.

However, when I run the above, nothing happens. can anyone guide me through this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run this script for 600x200 = 120,000 iterations. I don't know what machine you are working on, but unless you have strong hardware - it suppose to take **long time**. I guess that "nothing happens" is just your computer still running, trying to run through 120,000 iterations...

Also, you are collecting all those iterations into lists. You expect that a pythonic list will hold 120,000 values. I'm not really sure if it's possible. Try to work with numpy array instead. Same for matplotlib, I'm not sure if it's know to handle with plotting 120,000 values.

The graph you brought above is for 600 episodes, not all 120,000 values of all steps in every episodes.

To sum it up: start small. run 10 episodes, each for 10 steps or something like that. See if that works and build up from there.